# Trying to sign base64 encoded string. Read from variable instead of file

Tags: powershell, openssl, jwt, base64

I use the following command in Powershell to sign a base64 encoded string. It is reading currently from a file. Can I also let it directly take it from a variable?

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign jwtRS256.key -binary $payload | openssl enc -base64 -
```

It works if I use the following:

```
 openssl dgst -sha256 -sign jwtRS256.key -binary payload.b64 | openssl enc -base64 -A
```

Maybe it is very simple or it is not possible what I try to achieve.

This line is part of some steps that I try to follow to sign a concatenate of header.payload for JWT geneartion by using openssl.

Comment: I tried some other things myself and came up with the following:

$signature = Write-Output toBeSigned | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign jwtRS256.key -binary | openssl base64 -A

However this one is still containing unwanted newlines

Comment: Have you tried piping to openssl? `$payload | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign jwtRS256.key | openssl enc -base64 -`